# Matlab: Remove chars from string with unicode chars

Tags: matlab

I have a long string that looks like:

```
その他,-9999.00
その他,-9999.00
その他,-9999.00
その他,-9999.00
```

and so forth. I'd like to split at linebreak and remove everything up to a comma, and just keep the floats. So my output should be something like:

```
A = 
     [-9999.99 -9999.99 -9999.99 -9999.99]
```

Any idea how to do that relatively quickly (a few seconds at most)? There are close to a million lines in that string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is with `textscan`:

```
out = textscan(str, '%*s%f', 'delimiter', ',');
out = out{1};
```

Comment: Yes, textscan is better than `regexp`.

Comment: Does this take into account that there are several lines of these, i.e. does it separate by linebreak, too? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the input is in a file. And I'm also assuming that the file is UTF-8 encoded, otherwise this won't work.

My solution is a simple Perl script. No doubt it can be done with MATLAB, but different tools have different strengths. I wouldn't attempt numerical analysis with Perl, that's for sure.

**convert.pl**

```
print "A = \n      [ ";
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s/.*,//;
    print " ";
    print;
}
print " ]";
```

**input.txt**

```
その他,-9999.00
その他,-9999.00
その他,-9999.00
その他,-9999.00
```

**Command line**

```
perl convert.pl < input.txt > output.txt
```

**output.txt**

```
A = 
      [  -9999.00 -9999.00 -9999.00 -9999.00 ]
```

Comment: Thanks David. I'd prefer a script as well (I could do it in Ruby in no time), but would like to keep it in Matlab so that the future users aren't dependent on an external shell script. Appreciate the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer since I don't have access to matlab from home
The following can be used to split on tab. Use this to split on newline.

```
s=sprintf('one\ttwo three\tfour');
r=regexp(s,'\t','split')
% r = 'one' 'two three' 'four'
```

`help strtok` might be helpful as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use `regexp` with Matlab for your problem (with `str` containing your string):

```
out = regexp(str,[',([^,',char(10),']+)',char(10)],'tokens')
out =  cat(1,out{:});
str2double(out)
out =
       -9999
       -9999
       -9999
       -9999
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to extract the numeric parts and convert them to doubles is to use the functions [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) and [STR2NUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2num.html):

```
A = str2num(str(ismember(str,',.e-0123456789')));
```